# Self-registration with ClearQuest

Tags: clearquest

We have some need to allow self-registration with ClearQuest for some database. We have integrated CQ with LDAP. Appreciate your ideas on the same.

*One way i thought is too have link in CQ startup screen for self-registration which will get all relevant info from user and via perl create new account in CQ.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented below.

Allow user to login with special username used only for new user requests

The users only has permission to submit a new record of type "UserRequest" which is a stateful record type that contains fields that user can enter data in for their new user request. You can also restrict the user from creating or running any queries putting them in restricted mode.

Submit action will triggers creating new user, sends mail and move this to close state.